# Restore mouse wheel event javascript library

Tags: javascript, object, events, methods, npm

I am using [wheel-indicator](https://github.com/Promo/wheel-indicator) JS library. I like to restore the mouse wheel event which was originally set to `preventDefault()`.

I tried `indicator.setOptions({preventMouse:"false"})` as the instance method says "The only argument must be Object", but it does not work.

```
var indicator = new WheelIndicator({
    elem: document.querySelector('.element'),
    callback: function(e){
      console.log(e.direction);
      //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
  });

indicator.setOptions({preventMouse:"false"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indicator = new WheelIndicator({
    elem: document.querySelector('.element'),
    callback: function(e){
      console.log(e.direction);
      //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
  });

indicator.getOption('preventMouse'); // true
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: getOption() method returns option value instead of changing it, stated in Instance methods

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem isn't connected directly with plugin. Maybe preventDefault() to wheel event on element just doesn't work in your case?